# wget showing syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, wget

running in python console:  ( Windows)

```
>>> "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\wget-1.11.4-1-bin\bin\wget.exe" google.com
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\wget-1.11.4-1-bin\bin\wget.exe" google.com
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You cannot enter commands like this in the Python console. You have to enter it in a shell, in Windows it's `cmd`

Comment: This is not a Python command. You should not be using Python to run it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my ignorance.  It was mentioned as part of Juypter instructions then I thought probably it can be done through python console.